# Segue to TabBarView from ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I have a TabBarController as my start point. This has three ViewControllers for each of the three TabBarItems. Each of these is controlled by a NavigationController.

When the app starts the ViewController at tabindex0 appears.

On this VC I have a Start button that segues to a ViewController, that is not associated with the tab bar. I segue to this like so:

**HomeView.swift**

```
@objc func clickStart(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToStartTest", sender: self)
    }
```

When I am done with that VC (TestView) I want to go back AND change the tabindex to 1.

Currently I'm going back to the HomeView VC from TestView VC like so:

**TestView.swift**

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "testToRes", sender: self)
```

I need to specify tabindex1 when segueing. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you using an unwind segue to go back?

Comment: No, I'm just using performSegue (updated OP). This works but it opens on TabIndex 0 and I need it to go to TabIndex 1. If I segue to the Navigation Controller responsible for TabIndex1 it works BUT I don't get the tab bar

Comment: You should use an unwind segue, otherwise you will be pushing a new tab bar controller

Comment: Even though I'm not unwinding to the same tabindex?

Comment: You would need to select the required tab index as part of the unwind process

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. If you can show an example of this as an answer I can accept it should it work.